# Async function call inside jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks, jsx

I try to call the `getAuthor` function, inside the `function (line 24 -console.log)` everything is ok, but I don't know how I should call the `getAuthor` function (line 37) properly.

This is a component with Comments, in my database, inside the comment record I have only `authorId`, so I want to call the `getUser(authorId)` function to get other information, like `profilePhoto`, `name` etc.

```
   /* eslint-disable jsx-a11y/click-events-have-key-events */
/* eslint-disable jsx-a11y/no-noninteractive-element-interactions */
/* eslint-disable no-underscore-dangle */
/* eslint-disable import/no-cycle */
/* eslint-disable jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid */
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { getComments, getUser } from '../../actions/FetchData';
import '../../scss/base/_comments.scss';
import CommentForm from './CommentForm/CommentForm';

function Comments({ placeId }) {
  const [comments, setComments] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchMyData = async () => {
      const commentsFromDb = await getComments();
      setComments(commentsFromDb);
    };
    fetchMyData();
  }, []);

  const getAuthor = async (authorId) => {
    const authorFromDb = await getUser(authorId);
    console.log(authorFromDb.profilePhoto);
    return authorFromDb;
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Komentarze</h1>
      <div className="comments">
        {comments.filter((comment) => comment.placeId === placeId).reverse().map((comment) => (
          <div className="comment">
            <p>
              author:
              {' '}
              {getAuthor(comment.authorId)}
            </p>
            <p>
              subject:
              {' '}
              {comment.subject}
            </p>
            <p>
              date:
              {' '}
              {comment.date}
            </p>
            <p>
              message:
              {' '}
              {comment.message}
            </p>
            <p>
              o:
              {' '}
              {comment.placeId}
            </p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <CommentForm placeId={placeId} />
    </>
  );
}

Comments.propTypes = {
  placeId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default Comments;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that when you get the comments to map the comments and request the authors for the comments and then add a new property to your comment object that represents the author and then in render you can access the author properties easily

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [comments, setComments] = useState([]);
  const placeId = 1;

  async function getComments() {
    return [
      {
        placeId: 1,
        authorId: 1,
        subject: "subject",
        date: "21-2-2020"
      }
    ];
  }

  async function getUser(id) {
    return { profilePhoto: "Hi there", name: "Ob616" };
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getComments().then(async (commentsFromDb) => {
      for (let index = 0; index < commentsFromDb.length; index++) {
        const comment = commentsFromDb[index];

        comment.author = await getAuthor(comment.authorId);
      }

      console.log(commentsFromDb);
      setComments(commentsFromDb);
    });
  }, []);

  const getAuthor = async (authorId) => {
    const authorFromDb = await getUser(authorId);
    console.log(authorFromDb.profilePhoto);
    return authorFromDb;
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Komentarze</h1>
      <div className="comments">
        {comments
          .filter((comment) => comment.placeId === placeId)
          .reverse()
          .map((comment) => (
            <div className="comment">
              <p>author: {comment.author.name}</p>
              <p>subject: {comment.subject}</p>
              <p>date: {comment.date}</p>
              <p>message: {comment.message}</p>
              <p>o: {comment.placeId}</p>
            </div>
          ))}
      </div>

      <CommentForm placeId={placeId} /> 
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: I think that's it a good solution, but I have still problem when I try save comments "setComments(commentsFromDb)", inside "commnents" I have Promises, how can I get to PromiseResult? (Promises are fulfilled)

Comment: Try this 

`useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true;
    getComments().then(commentsFromDb => {
        if (mounted) {
            commentsFromDb = commentsFromDb.map(async comment => {
                comment.author = await getAuthor(comment.authorId)
                return comment;
            })

            setComments(commentsFromDb);
        }
    });

    return () => mounted = false;
}, []);`

Comment: It's still this same

Comment: Check this code Sandbox, I made it working there

[SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-almeida-3ofzd?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand solution from this SandBox. Is it certainly proper version of code? Where do you add 'author' to 'comment' like here 'comment.author = await getAuthor(comment.authorId)' etc?

Comment: I have no clue why the code didn't save, but take another look now it's updated and I updated the code in the answer as well

Comment: Thank you very much! It works and everything is okay

Comment: You're very welcome

Answer (score 1):

You can't call async function in JSX, it will return a promise. You have to resolve the promise first.

One solution is to do the same thing you did with `comments`, (putting it `useEffect` hook)

Like this:

```
...
const [comments, setComments] = useState([]);
const [author, setAuthor] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchMyData = async () => {
    const commentsFromDb = await getComments();
    setComments(commentsFromDb);
    const authorFromDb = await getAuthor(commentsFromDb.authorId);
    setAuthor(authorFromDb );
  };
  fetchMyData();
}, []);
...
```